# What is "resources" in Google Chrome Develper Tools Network Section?

Tags: page-speed, google-chrome

My page is 1.4MB in size (Calculated by GTMetrix).

When I checked with developer tools, I can also confirm that in "transferred" indicator in Network tab. (image below)

However I don't understand what is "resources" area. It says 3.2MB in my website. But what is it ?

Here the image, I highligted it with yellow:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I did some research and found this: https://www.lifewire.com/web-browser-developer-tools-3988965.

> "Resources: This is where you can inspect cookies, local storage, app
>   cache, and other local data sources used by the current Web page or
>   application"

Since resources includes local data such as cookies and app cache, it would be possible for it to vary significantly from the data you actually download in your page.